# Trying to fetch Facebook pages from Java returns forced 302

Tags: java, facebook

Is there any way to get past the Forced 302 that happens when fetching any Facebook page from Java?

It tells me that I have an unsupported browser. I was thinking I should just spoof the user agent to the newest Chrome/Firefox.

This is the exact error its throwing:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 forced.302
Location: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Debug: fLkC8ZEgg/6RmxdQEkZOzAqGhhDcqGxnS8HToqpn0Cs=
Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2014 16:07:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you just want to fetch the page so you can then parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will probably do something like check the user agent against a list of good and bad user agents  - the "bad" user agents being unsupported browsers, most likely very old versions - in order to decide whether to serve the content.

If, like you mention, you were to spoof the user agent to a new(er) browser, you will get a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response.